# How do I expand treeview node by clicking on section header (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, treeview

How do I expand the node by clicking on the item text?

Purpose is to make it easier to expand or close a node, apart from depending on the Expander arrow button.

Comment: you know you can double-click the header to expand/collapse the node :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.  This toggles the item expanded/collapsed, but you could do `item.IsExpanded = true;` instead if you like.

```
TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(treeView.SelectedItem);
item.IsExpanded = !item.IsExpanded;
```

You can fire this code in the mouse-button-up event handler of your label.  If you put it in the mouse-down event handler, the tree view item won't have been selected yet.